# Sending data from AppleScript to FileMaker records

Tags: applescript, filemaker

I'm computing some data in AppleScript that I'd like to then insert into a specific FileMaker record. Here's my AppleScript:

```
on sendDataToFM(FileNameWithExtension, ClipLength)
    tell application "FileMaker Pro Advanced"

        show every record of database 1
        show (every record whose cell "File Name" = FileNameWithExtension)

        repeat with i from 1 to (count record)
            set MatchingRecord to record i
            set data cell "CLIP LENGTH" of MatchingRecord to ClipLength
        end repeat

    end tell
end sendDataToFM

...

my sendDataToFM('Some Video.mov', '00:01:22.55')
```

Everything works ***except*** the line

```
set data cell "CLIP LENGTH" of MatchingRecord to ClipLength
```

The error returned is

```
(*Can’t get cell "CLIP LENGTH" of {"Some Video.mov",  ... }.*)
```

The script finds the right record, and the FileMaker field name is definitely "CLIP LENGTH". What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try also set cellValue of cell "CLIP LENGTH" of MatchingRecord to ClipLength?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
on sendDataToFM(FileNameWithExtension, ClipLength)
    tell application "FileMaker Pro"
        show (every record of current table whose cell "File Name" = FileNameWithExtension)
        repeat with i from 1 to (count record)
            set cell "CLIP LENGTH" of (record i) to ClipLength
        end repeat
    end tell
end sendDataToFM

my sendDataToFM("Some Video.mov", "00:01:22.55")
```