# Get UTC time in FileMaker 11 scripts

Tags: filemaker

How can I write a native FileMaker 11 script that returns the UTC time and saves this in a field or a variable? I would like to avoid plugins and AppleScript. A negative answer would also be helpful.

I would like to have functionality similar to this AppleScript:

```
set UTCTime to do shell script "date -u"
display dialog UTCTime
```

Output:

```
Thu Jun 16 07:10:42 UTC 2016
```

The following script step would work but was first introduced in FileMaker 11.
http://www.filemaker.com/help/13/fmp/en/html/func_ref2.32.27.html

```
Get ( CurrentTimeUTCMilliseconds )
```

Returns:

```
63568967107528
```

I've also researched methods for determining the local time zone, but these also depend on having the UTC time first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to get UTC time *natively* in FileMaker Pro 11. The only times it get can is the local client time or the host time. Both are "wall clock" times - with no indication of the offset from UTC.

If you don't want to use a plugin or OS-level script, then I believe your only resource would be using a web-viewer - either by getting the UTC from an external service (provided your system is on-line), or by having it run JavaScript locally.

Note, however, that getting the result of JavaScript run in a web viewer back into FileMaker is far from trivial (see, for example, http://fmforums.com/topic/58535-scraping-data-from-a-javascript-variable/?do=findComment&comment=277317) and, in my experience, rather flimsy. If you really need this, I would recommend you do use a plugin or an OS script.

Comment: Thanks again, Michael!

Comment: Can you recommend then how to do this with AppleScript? What's the most robust way to get the output back into FileMaker.

Comment: I'll post that as a separate question.

Comment: The best way is to have AppleScript set a FMP field.

Comment: I'll try with a method similar to the one here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15772345/sending-data-from-applescript-to-filemaker-records